Anyone here implemented Theme change successfully with Voyager in jetpack compose
I have been trying to implement theme change in 2 of my apps but it being a hassle after extensive debug period, I figured the common thing between them is that both app uses Voyager because they are a multiplatform app.
I figured after a successful theme change and the state changes, Voyager doesn't recompose to reflect the current (newly)selected theme until I close the app and open again.
So my question now is had anyone faced similar issue and what advice will you give me on how to overcome it or probably a code example.
